Why "rojos brazos abiertos" in Gabriela Mistral's poem Anochecer?
In Gabriela Mistral's poem "Anochecer" (which can be found in the blog post Gabriela Mistral. Poemas. but not on the presumably official Gabriela Mistral website), part of the posthumously published Poema de Chile, the first few lines are as follows (emphasis mine):

Cae el día del Señor
con rojos brazos abiertos
y nos abraza la noche
de los hombres y los ciervos.

Translation:

The Lord's day falls
with red arms open
and the night of men
and deer embraces us.

This translation uses the same word order as the Spanish text for the phrase in bold, which uses the syntax "adjective, noun, adjective". In English, adjectives usually come before the noun. You can say "with his arms wide open" and "she threw her arms wide open", but in that case my understanding is that "wide" modifies "open" rather than the arms.
In Spanish, by contrast, adjectives tend to come after the noun; they can come before the noun"especially when they are used for emphasis or when they convey a subjective quality".
Colour adjectives such as "rojos" (red) are usually placed after a noun and, in this case, "rojos" does not need to come before "brazos" because of the metre. So what is the special meaning that is conveyed by placing "rojos" before "brazos" instead of after it?
